# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_apscheduler' when I migrate my file with heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, apscheduler

I want to update my heroku site with this command `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, but the error appeared:

```
»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.60.2.
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ mighty-harbor-18334... up, run.5980 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                               
 main()
File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main 
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
 utility.execute()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute
 django.setup()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
 apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
 app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 223, in create 
 import_module(entry)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                               return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_apscheduler'
```

I installed django_apscheduler with `pip install django_apscheduler` for sure. My python version is **3.10.2**, and in my **settings.py**, the app module is in INSTALLED_APPS such:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
    'django_apscheduler',
]
```

I am not sure why the `ModuleNotFoundError` would occured, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you put `django_apscheduler` in your `requirements.txt` file so that Heroku installs it?

Comment: @0sVoid Yes I did and the error still exist. I would like to create a new app to see if the problem still exist

Answer (score 1):

You forgot after 'myapp' put a comma in INSTALLED_APPS